# Код успешно выполняется из CMD, но выдаёт ошибку при исполении из PyCharm

Tags: python, cmd, pycharm, python-3.6

Я начинающий автоматизатор на Python. Сейчас пытаюсь автоматизировать тестирование интерфейса и столкнулась со следующей проблемой: один и тот же код отрабатывает, если его запускать из CMD (работаю на Windows 10), если его туда скопипастить, но при запуске из PyCharm или исполнении именно .py файла из CMD выдаёт ошибку.
Собственно часть кода:

```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector(Creds.login_field).send_keys('ХХХ')
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector(Creds.password_field).send_keys('ХХХ')
  driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(),"Войти")]').click()
```

Если это исполнять из CMD, то кнопка успешно нажимается. Если исполнять файл, то выдаёт следующую ошибку:

```
  raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
  selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:
  Element <button name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success">...</button> is not clickable at point (478, 373). 
  Other element would receive the click: <div class="modal-backdrop fade"></div>
```

В чём может быть проблема, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: А как это вы так хитро запускаете код на Питоне копипастя его в CMD?

Comment: Открываем консоль, пишем там python.exe, Enter. Копипастим код, Enter. И так можно построчно код проверять

Comment: Ну так бы и писали - "в режиме repl" или, по-простому, при интерактивном вводе. CMD в вашем вопросе - лишняя сущность же.

Comment: А если воткнуть sleep(10) между командами, то в pycharm проходит?

Comment: Пробовала воткнуть sleep(15), не помогло.

Comment: Хотя вот поставила sleep(25) и помогло. Спасибо за толковую мысль!

Comment: @GalinaMokrinskaya нельзя писать тест исходя из реализации. Вот завтра ваш тест опять сломается, вы что будете делать? Чинить тест или чинить код? Если первое - то зачем вообще такой тест нужен?

Answer (score 0):

По всей видимости, ваша кнопка спрятана в каком-то модальном диалоге, у которого есть анимация появления на экране. При интерактивном вводе команд эти самые команды вводятся с задержкой, и модальный диалог успевает появиться. А при пакетном выполнении тех же самых команд задержки нет, и модальный диалог спрятан (о чем можно догадаться по одинокому классу `fade`, у открытого модального диалога должны быть классы `fade in`).

Вам нужно или дождаться появления класса `in` на диалоге, или просто поставить задержку перед началом работы с диалогом. Если вы решите пойти вторым путем - избегайте соблазна подсмотреть нужную задержку в коде или определить экспериментально, берите ее из [нефункциональных требований](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9#%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) к отзывчивости интерфейса.